# Include device location and multiple map markers in camera bounds

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

We're displaying a number of map markers on the map representing various objects which are retrieved either from a cache or from an asynchronous network call. When these objects are retrieved, we update the camera to ensure all markers are within view:

```
 LatLngBounds bounds = mBoundsBuilder.build();
 mMapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50, 100, 50, 30));
```

We're interested in adding the user's location to the map, and have done so using the `LocationComponent` provided by MapBox as shown [in this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/show-a-users-location/).

The problem is that when the `LocationComponent` has `locationComponent .setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING)` set as shown, the camera will focus on the user's location, without accommodating the markers previously set. Setting the camera mode to `CameraMode.NONE` allows the markers to be shown using the code snippet above, however in this case the user's location will not be accommodated in the `mBoundsBuilder`.

The obvious solution seemed to be to listen for location updates and manually add the coordinates to the `mBoundsBuilder` so that the user's location is taken into account. This, however, has a number of problems, such as:

1. Callbacks for location changes can be invoked many times, while the `mBoundsBuilder` should only contain a single set of coordinates for the user's location, the rest of the objects being the previously added markers.
2. Location updates are asynchronous, and `getLastKnownLocation` will often return `null`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a *default*, built in way to show a user's location while making sure the camera accommodates map markers?
2. If no default option exists, how can this be properly implemented?

**Version:**
`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:6.8.1`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this -> https://www.github.com/bkhezry/MapDrawingTools it helps in drawing polygons on a map.